# Did Conan Doyle write Sherlock Holmes?

Tags: history, literature

I came across the claim that sir Arthur Conan Doyle didn't write the Sherlock Holmes stories and probably just, at most, edited them.

Normally such a claim would not be taken seriously. But the person who made the suggestion was Martin Gardner, an hero to many skeptics and a debunker of many ideas in pseudoscience and the paranormal. For those who are too young to remember him, he was the author of the Mathematical Games column in Scientific American for several decades and a leading skeptic and science writer (see bio [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Gardner)).

In an essay included in his book *[Science Good, Bad and Bogus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0879755733)* published in 1981 he argues that the rational and scientific character of Holmes could not have been produced by a character like Conan Doyle. Conan Doyle was a credulous believer in spriritualism and fairies and a careless observer of psychic demonstrations. He was such a believer that he refused to believe that Houdini was performing tricks and not real magic even after Houdini denied being a psychic.

I doubt Gardner's argument as it seems to be based purely on what someone is capable of imagining. So my question is *is there any other reason to doubt that he wrote the stories and invented the character?*

Comment: The essay is titled "The Irrelevance of Conan Doyle", but I can't find a copy of it on the internet.

Comment: @Jivlain That is right. I have the book (since before the internet!) so unless there is a Kindle copy I'm not sure how easy it will be for others to access online. It seems to be in print, though.

Comment: Hmm... as someone who grew up on both Doyle's AND Gardner's books, this makes me feel all schitzo.

Comment: The books themselves say in black and white that they were written by Dr Watson, and anything a Sherlock Holmes book says can be taken on trust to be true.

Comment: Do you (or does he) have any evidence whatsoever for his assertion (and no, his reasoning doesn't make for evidence)? If not, it's effectively discredited automatically. According to his reasoning Tolkien can't have written the Lord of the Rings as he was a scientists and the LoTR is fiction...

Comment: So the arguement is that this guy can not imagine that the other guy could imagine a fictional character...

Comment: @Chad yes, that is the argument. I posted it partially because Gardner also hinted that some similar arguments about other authors had been resolved by further evidence. And note the similarities to the Shakespeare debate here: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/6621/who-wrote-shakespeares-plays . It i interesting to compare the logic in both cases.

Comment: Let's not forget that Conan-Doyle hated Sherlock Holmes the character, or came to hate him, to the point of killing him off. That's plausible behaviour for someone writing a character whose philosophy he disagreed with.

Comment: It seems Martin Gardner thinks that every fictional character **must** be a Mary Sue, and no writer is capable of imagining a character who does not exactly share all the beliefs/ideologies of the author.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think Gardner's argument doesn't make much sense:

1. A. Conan Doyle did not invent detective stories or the super-rational detective character, see Dupin in Murders in the Rue Morgue by E. A. Poe. [source](http://www.indiana.edu/~liblilly/holmes/predecessors.shtml)
2. We have Doyle's handwritten manuscripts, letters, biographies. There is no real contempt that he is the author. [source](http://www.bestofsherlock.com/conan-doyle-manuscripts.htm)
3. The whole argument is preposterous. Carl Sagan wrote a successful fiction book about aliens, being a skeptic. Why can't a non-skeptic write a book about a rationalist? [source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_%28novel%29)

Comment: I mostly agree. Not sure that the carl sagan reference reinforces the argument, though. His protagonist in Contact, Ellie Arroway, was the epitome of rationality (not in the movie, though, which made her out to be some mush headed romantic destroying much of what made the book great). On the other hand Sagan was able to create a sympathetic portrait of a conservative religious leader with convictions and attitudes the opposite of his own rationalist beliefs.

Comment: L Ron Hubbard wrote a book about how he could create a crazy fictional religion and people would flock to it.  They he had an epiphany and realized the truth that is Scientology.

Comment: The more often I read this answer, the less convincing it is. OK, point 2 may be definitive. Points 1 and 3 are irrelevant. Point 1 isn’t even contested. Point 3 addresses a fundamentally different (preposterous) claim. Doyle may have written a character which he was not sympathetic to. But a character essentially dismantling Doyle’s core beliefs? Much harder to swallow. Even point 2 doesn’t make it impossible that Doyle’s merely edited somebody else’s brainchild. **I do not believe this** but I can definitely see why intelligent people would, and I don’t think points 1 & 3 address this.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Point 1 and 3 address the argument as presented by the OP - I can do no better than address the argument as presented! Point 2 presents the expert consensus as supported by the accepted literary/historical evidence which *must* be taken as the correct history unless there is contrary proof. If anyone, including Gardner, wants to propose a different theory, then the burden of proof is on them. It's quite easy to prove that Conan Doyle was not the author (via, say, a dated registered letter). No such proof has been presented by Gardner so his argument is unsustainable.

Comment: Besides that, my job is to present the available evidence, which in this case points to Gardner being wrong, not to convince the reader that I am right. I don't have a position, literary historians do.

Comment: @Sklivvz A misunderstanding perhaps. Despite my caveat, I take your point 2 at face value. I’m still not convinced what you are trying to address with points 1 and 3. Nothing in the question claims (or doubts a claim) that Doyle *invented* detective stories. However, this is what your point 1 addresses. Point 3 draws a false analogy with a superficially similar but actually completely different situation.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, I think the misunderstanding is the following: I am answering "here any other reason to doubt that he wrote the stories and invented the character?", whereas you are expecting an answer to "Did Conan Doyle write Sherlock Holmes?".

Comment: @Sklivvz Granted, this makes (1) fit. Still not convinced about (3). The more I think about it, the more convinced I am that in order to write this Doyle *and* believe what he believed really must have had psychoses, rendering him incoherent (well, that much is pretty obvious from the Houdini episode alone).

Answer (score 9):

This exact question, of Martin Gardner's article about Conan Doyle, is addressed (definitively!) by Raymond Smullyan in his piece [**"Ambrose, Gardner and Doyle"**](http://g4gardner.pbworks.com/f/mm-smullyan.pdf), which is part of the ["proceedings"](http://www.g4g4.com/g4g9/dowboo1.pdf) of the recent [Gathering For Gardner](http://www.g4g4.com/) (G4G9, 2010).

It's a very short and amusing "play" which is worth reading in the [original](http://g4gardner.pbworks.com/f/mm-smullyan.pdf), but anyone who is impatient can skip to the section on the last page, called "Discussion".

Spoiler:

> It's a hoax by Gardner, and he said so himself to Smullyan.

Comment: Great find. It could also be a spoof, though (or does this lead to some sort of meta-spoof infinite regression?)

Comment: @matt_black: That is exactly the point of Smullyan's article. :-)

Comment: Now we have Smullyans assertion, without proof, that Gardner admitted a hoax to him in a personal communication, which nobody can check. I doubt that an intelligent man like Smullyan would have presented such flawed evidence. The play’s discussion must be a fake.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Yes, you get the idea. :-) (The next step is for someone to allude to your history of intelligent posts on Stack Exchange...)

Comment: This also reminds me of Godel Escher Bach (the chapter that "fools" the reader by signalling that it is over because it is full of unusual typos and situation). I will need to speak about this with that good friend of mine, the Tortoise.

Comment: Sadly the links all seem broken now. :-( See page 13 (page 17 of the PDF) [here](http://www.cfrd.cl/~moises/DVD/05Bibliografia%20-%20Geometria%20Sagrada/Matematica%20Recreativa/Martin%20Gardner/Martin%20Gardner%20-%20The%20Mathemagician%20and%20Pied%20Puzzler%20-%20A%20Collection%20in%20Tribute%20to%20Martin%20Gardner.pdf).